# JS reduce object complexity by specific fields

Tags: javascript

I have such an object with nested object properties.

```
const obj = {
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 info: {
   data: "info"
 },
 issue: {
   data: "issue"
 }
}
```

I exactly know the name of the fields with an object (info and issue), and the nested object format is always the same (data property).

I need to get such output:

```
const obj = {
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 info: "info",
 issue: "issue"
}
```

Here you can see my solution:

```js
const obj = {
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 info: {
   data: "info"
 },
 issue: {
   data: "issue"
 }
}


const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => v ? {...acc, [k]: typeof v === 'object' ? v.data : v} : acc , {})

console.log(res);
```

Is it good enough? As for me, such complex reduce doesn't look too much readably and can be simplified. Are there any simpler solutions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` is rarely a good option unless you're doing functional programming with predefined, tested reducer functions.

In this case, you don't even need a loop as you often would; just a simple object initializer with spread syntax does the job:

```
const res = {
    ...obj,
    info: obj.info.data,
    issue: obj.issue.data,
};
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = {
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 info: {
   data: "info"
 },
 issue: {
   data: "issue"
 }
}

const res = {
    ...obj,
    info: obj.info.data,
    issue: obj.issue.data,
};

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

almost identical to your, except avoiding type of

```js
const obj = {
 name: "name",
 surname: "surname",
 info: {
   data: "info"
 },
 issue: {
   data: "issue"
 }
}


const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [k, v]) => {
  acc[k] =  v.data || v;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(res);
```